# I am trying to use google maps with flutter with map_view: "^0.0.10" but I get an error

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I am making a project that involves flutter and google maps intergration but unfortunately I am not able to do it because whenever I try to use the package map_view: "^0.0.10" in pubspec.yaml it is not getting installed.
I am getting an error saying

Package uri has no versions that match >=0.11.1 <0.12.0 derived from:
- map_view 0.0.10 depends on version ^0.11.1
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1

I tried to find the fix but not able to
I even installed uri but it also did not fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNqCr.png)

Comment: Hi :). Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an open issue.

[map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) package depens on [uri](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uri) package version `0.11.1` that fails to install at the date of this answer:

- https://github.com/google/uri.dart/issues/29
- https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/22

Accordint to this: https://github.com/google/uri.dart/pull/28 there is some conflict with flutter test dev SDK.

So if you wanna give it a try you could comment this lines:

```
#dev_dependencies:
  #flutter_test:
    #sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, I figured it out after going through the issues in the map_view repo

Comment: I am facing another issue right now
The map is working great but in my app, I don't want the top toolbar I have been trying to do it but I am not able to get it work.
It would be great if you could help me out.